# using entity manager clear() and also having a listener for doctrine batch processing

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, batch-processing

I am running a batch process which takes an array and loops through adding new entites via doctrine.

Because of the size of the array, I am finding that I need to use `$em->clear()`

Even when I use `$em->clear('my/entity')` I get the issues of:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship
```

I have traced it down to the listeners on that entity that I need to clear.

**How can I clear an entity in doctrine that also has listeners?**

I have also tried `$em->detach()` with no luck

---

Current solution:

```
$this->em->persist($product);
$this->em->flush();
$this->em->clear(get_class($product));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have come up with:

pseudo code:

```
foreach ($this->recordBlocks as $recordBlock) {
    $this->getExtraEntities();
    $this->importRecords($progress, $recordBlock);
    $this->em->clear();
}
```

Somehow if you have the persists and flushes inside a different method, then the clear will not affect the listeners.

So, what I did:

Queried for my records with a different entity manager as usual
but then instead of passing the whole query results to the `importRecords` method,
I passed just a small block (about 10 records) to it, and when it finishes then I run a clear on my entity manager.

I then get the few other entities I need for the persist from the `getExtraEntites` method which the clear got rid of.

**I had my clear method set once the method that flushes the entities returns**
(so I run in batches, otherwise memory will go bang)

---

I am putting my solution here, but I do not believe it is the best one, so will not accept it yet...